# Android - dynamically load class into memory

Tags: java, android, reflection, dexclassloader

[DexClassLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html) is great but works only by loading the compiled class as dex/jar file from the internal/external storage.

How can I load class directly into memory, without writing anything to the card first?

I am aware of the [Java-Runtime-Compiler](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Runtime-Compiler) (compiles String to Class on-the-fly) from Peter Lawrey, which would be perfect, but it does not work in android.

Answer (score 0):

The general principles for writing Java class loaders apply here as well, so basically what you need to do is write a class loader that can produce a `Class` instance, for example by invoking `defineClass()`. Of course this involves creating a valid array of dex bytecode. I have not done so yet, and besides very special occasions I would refraim from attempting to do so anyway. If you follow this road, remember to only use classloader features that have been present in Java 5 and 6.

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas stated, you can reflectively invoke the protected `defineClass()` method of the ClassLoader into which you would like to load your class.

Here's an example of how this could be achieved:

```
public static Class<?> loadClass(byte[] code, ClassLoader loadInto) throws InvocationTargetException
{
    try {
        Method m = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("defineClass", byte[].class, int.class, int.class);
        m.setAccessible(true); // Make sure we can invoke the method
        return (Class<?>) m.invoke(loadInto, code, 0, code.length);
    }
    // An exception should only be thrown if the bytecode is invalid
    // or a class with the same name is already loaded
    catch (NoSuchMethodException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e){ throw new RuntimeException(e); }
}
```

Although, what I'm getting the feeling that you're referring to is runtime compilation of a String containing valid Java into bytecode, based on the link you included. Though I do not know of any way of doing this, I would recommend you take a look at this: https://github.com/linkedin/dexmaker

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by [InMemoryDexClassLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/InMemoryDexClassLoader)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.